# Ruby, hash and object_id

Tags: ruby, memory

I use Ruby 2.2.2.

```
irb(main):002:0> str = "abc"
=> "abc"
irb(main):003:0> str2 = "abc"
=> "abc"
irb(main):004:0> str.hash
=> -340360941
irb(main):005:0> str2.hash
=> -340360941
irb(main):006:0> str.object_id
=> 3702564
irb(main):007:0> str2.object_id
=> 24864312
irb(main):009:0> str == str2
=> true
irb(main):010:0> str.eql? str2
=> true
```

Why `str` and `str2` have same hash, but different `object_id`? According to doc [hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-hash) and [object_id](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-object_id), no two active objects will share an id, so `str` and `str2` have different `object_id`, but how to understand their `hash` are same?

Could anybody tell something about this? My guess is that `"abc"` only occupy one memory space, and both `str` and `str2` referenced to the same memory space.

If someone could explain it in how memory is allocated, that will be great.

Comment: Two different objects, which are equal should have the same hash value.

Comment: @Santhosh Totally agree. Could you help explain the difference between `hash` and `object_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My guess is that "abc" only occupy one memory space, and both `str` and `str2` referenced to the same memory space.

Whether that was true, their `object_id` were the same. The string is created twice and `str` instance has nothing to do with `str2` instance. Otherwise, `str[1] = "A"` led to both variables change, transforming `str2`‘s value to `aAc`.

When objects‘ values are equal, their hashes are to be equal for quick lookup/search etc.

E.g. John Smith from Ohio and John Smith from Oklahoma share the same name, what makes their `hash` equal, but since they are definitely not the same person, their `object_id` differ.

Comment: It means that `str` and `str2` only occupy one memory space, they share the same memory address, right?

Comment: Once again. Whether they shared the same memory address, any changes applied to `str` would be reflected in `str2`. They are totally different objects, occupying different memory spaces and having nothing in common in general. `str == str2` is evaluated to `true` because of particular implementation of [`String#==`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3D-3D) method, which apparently compares _values_.

Answer (score 0):

`object_id` (and the corresponding `equal?` method) are concerned with object identity: are these 2 objects the exact same object? subclasses don't (or at least shouldn't) override this.

On the other hand `==` and `eql?` are more about object values: do these two objects represent the same value? This is of course dependant on the class, so it is quite possible to have two different objects (their object_id is different) that are equal in this respect. The `hash` method's contract that equal objects must have equal hash value is for `eql?`, so it's normal that two objects can have different object_id but have the same hash.

In your example your 2 strings are different objects that, at that particular point in time, happen to contain the same sequence of bytes